# How can i resolve this php mysql loop?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?

$sql = dbquery("SELECT `id`, `title`, `description` FROM `content` LIMIT 0,12 ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $id          = $row["id"];
    $title       = $row["title"];
    $description = $row["description"];
    $content     = '
    <div class="description-box">
    <p>page id: ' . $id . '</p>
    <p>' . $title . '</p>
    <p>' . $description . '</p>
    </div>';
}

echo $content;
?>
```

// notice: div class="description-box"

// How can i replace that with: div class="description-box nopadding" after every 3 output divs ?

Example of html generated code:

```
<div class="description-box nopadding">
// content
</div>
<div class="description-box">
// content
</div>
<div class="description-box">
// content
</div>
<div class="description-box">
// content
</div>
```

// then again the div with `nopadding`

Comment: Use a counter variable, divide it by 3 each time you're in the loop and if the remainder of integer division is 0 - you have your "every 3rd time" iteration.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: You should also avoid using short-open tags like that (`<? ?>`). `<?php ?>` isn't *that* much extra work, even if you have to type it 10 times on a page, and it ensures that your server will support the code. `<?= ?>` is a different story, and is still valid regardless of whether `short_open_tags` are enabled on your server (as of PHP 5.4).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div class="description-box'.(($c++%3==0)?' nopadding':'').'">
```

remember to init `$c`

It's very simple:

if remainder of division `$c` by 3 is equal 0 add `' nopadding'` string, otherwise add `''` stirng

```
0 % 3 == 0 // add
1 % 3 == 1
2 % 3 == 2
3 % 3 == 0 // add
4 % 3 == 1
...
```

Syntax:

```
echo true ? "it's true" : "it's false"; // it's true
echo (5 % 3); // 2, remainder of 5/3 division
$c = 0;
echo $c++; // 0
echo $c;   // 1
```

Comment: Since you posted shorter code, you should explain what it does and why you opted to go for the short version instead of the longer one.

Comment: this is not working very well... it's returning two `description-box` then a `description-box nopadding` then another two `description-box` and so on...

Comment: @m3tsys - Peter showed you the principle, don't expect to be spoon-fed, use the example and adjust it to suit your needs. It's not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$sql = dbquery("SELECT `id`, `title`, `description` FROM `content` LIMIT 0,12 ");
$counter = 0; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
$id = $row["id"];   
$title = $row["title"];
$description = $row["description"];
if($counter%3 == 0)
{
 $div = '<div class="description-box nopadding">'
}
else
{
 $div = '<div class="description-box">';
}
 content = $div.'
 <p>page id: '.$id.'</p>
 <p>'.$title.'</p>
 <p>'.$description.'</p>
 </div>';
 $counter++;
}

echo $content;  ?>
```

Comment: This is just wrong. How can you put `if` statement in string?

Comment: Didnt see the string.. adjusted accordingly.

Comment: After three of your edits it's still wrong. `content = '$div` should be `$content = $div.'` and `$counter` should start from `0`

Comment: Ok. I see it now. He needs it to be first.